# Images won't animate

Tags: ios, xcode, image, swift, animation

I have been trying to get some dice images to animate by using an image based animation, and displaying several images of different numbers on the dice before they display the random image. Here is the code for the `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Links to the image views
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage0: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage4: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage5: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage6: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage7: UIImageView!

    // Setting the RandomImages function to a constant 
    let randomImages = RandomImages()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Array of animation images
        var animationImages:[UIImage] = [
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!
        ]

        // Animation duration and repeat count
        var animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0
        var animationRepeatCount: Int = 1


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Motion to roll dice
    override func motionBegan(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        println("Motion Began")

    }

    override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        // Trying to get one of the dice to roll
        self.dieImage0.startAnimating() 

        dieImage0.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage1.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage2.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage3.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage4.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage5.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage6.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage7.image = randomImages.randomDice();

        println("Motion Ended")
    }

    override func motionCancelled(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        println("Motion Cancelled")
    }


}
```

And the code for the `RandomImages` file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct RandomImages {

    var diceImages:[UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!
    ]

    func randomDice() -> UIImage {
        var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(diceImages.count)
        var unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
        var randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)

        return diceImages[randomNumber]
    }

}
```

[image: Storyboard and assistant editor]

Any help on how to follow the DRY principal is also wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does't make much sense. You are creating variables on your view controller named `animationImages`, `animationDuration` and `animationRepeatCount`. That doesn't do anything.

You need to set those properties on a `UIImageView`. Assuming `dieImage0` is a `UIImageView` that is hooked up as an outlet in your view controller, the code might look like this:

```
func animateDieImage0
{
  dieImage0.animationImages = [
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!
        ]
  dieImage0.animationDuration = 1.0
  dieImage0.animationRepeatCount = 1
  dieImage0.startAnimating()
}
```

And by the way, repeating the same 6 images multiple times is the wrong way to make the animation repeat. (It's a huge waste of memory.) That's what repeatCount is for.

Comment: Do I put this code in my 'motionEnded' or 'viewDidLoad'? I also get an error that says to put a semicolon between 'animationImages' and ':'.

Comment: I didn't delete the type from your variable declaration. I edited my answer. As to where you put that code, it depends. When do you want your image view to start animating? When the view controller first displays, or at some other point? That code will cause the animation to start. If you want the image view to animate immediately, put it in viewDidLoad. If you want it to trigger on your motionEnded event, put it there.

Comment: You should probably set up the animationImages array in viewDidLoad, and then call startAnimating() wherever you want to trigger your animation.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing the animation. I tried putting ' dieImage0.startAnimating()' in the motionEnded and nothing, 'dieImage0.animateDieImage0()' gives an error and so does 'animateDieImage'.

Comment: The answer to my problem is in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358297/using-a-loop-for-adding-attributes-to-multiple-uiimageviews) question.